# Laurent polynomial rings are integrally closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. Consider the Laurent polynomial ring $R=k[x_1,x_1^{-1},\ldots ,x_n,x_n^{-1}]$. I need to show that $R$ is integrally closed. For $n=1$ I have proved that it will be integrally closed as localisation at every prime ideal will give a DVR and hence a integrally closed ring.

I need some help to prove for $n>1$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you not yet proved that localization preserves integral closure? That's easily found, e.g. here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Localization_Preserves_Integral_Closure

$R=k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ is a UFD, hence integrally closed, and the Laurent polynomials are just a localization of that.

Comment: localisation at the monomials?

Comment: @2015 Yes, to form a single multiplicatively closed set, you could use monomials. I think you can also think of it as a sequence of localizations one-at-a-time, too.

Comment: You could also localize at the product (or monomial) $x_1\cdots x_n$.

Comment: @Youngsu Ah, yeah, you do only need that one :)